# Can I distinguish elements after act with a group?

Tags: group-actions, amenability

Let $H = \prod_{i=1}^\infty H_i$ be a product of discrete, countable, amenable groups $H_i$ and $G$ be a countable group.
Let $x: H \to G$ be a function and recall that $H$ acts on the set of functions from $H$ to $G$ by
$(\alpha_h x)(\tilde{h}) = x(h^{-1}\tilde{h})$

Suppose that we have $h,h'\in H$, $h= (h_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$, $h'=(h'_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$
such that $\alpha_h x \neq \alpha_{h'} x$. Is it true that there exists $J \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$\alpha_{h_1\dots h_J}x \neq \alpha_{h'_1 \dots h'_J} x$?

I suppose that it could be false but I don't have a counterexample. Moreover, I don't know if there is a general theory that studies these things.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I can self-answer my question:
Take $H$ as above and $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$,

$x(\tilde{h})= \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if there exists} \, J \in \mathbb{N} \, \mbox{such that} \, \tilde{h}_j = 0 \, \mbox{for every}\, j>J\\
1 &\mbox{if not};
\end{cases}$

and consider $h\in H$ any element with $x(h)=1$. Then,
$(\alpha_h x)(\tilde h)=x(h^{-1}\tilde{h}) \neq x(\tilde{h})$ (for example, $1 = x(h) \neq x(1)$)

but for every projection of $h$, say $h_1\dots h_J$, we have that
$$\theta_{h_1...h_J}x(\tilde h) = x(\tilde h)$$